# Add ssh authorized key and hide it in the authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh, security

Is it possible to add an ssh key to a system and make hidden (at least at first glance) from the user?

UPD: Recently I was participating in a CTF and had access to another team's machine. I wanted to persist my access in a way that they won't notice. This is why I am looking for such stuff.

Comment: Make all the keys the same size and remove the comments and they're all pretty much indistinguishable at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

No,

Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Recently I was participating at a CTF and had access to another team's machine. I wanted to persist my access in a way that they won't notice.

Comment: @Bat Look up `ControlPersist` in `man ssh_config`.

Comment: @muru AFAIK that's still going to show up in netstat which is the first thing anyone would check.

Comment: @user11 if they're relying on the team not noticing new keys in their authorized_keys, they might as well rely on them not using netstat to check current connections.